# Configure SSL binding for RESTful WCF. How?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest, web-config

My current config looks like so:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <!--Set limit to 5 megabytes-->
        <standardEndpoint helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="5242880">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                        maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                        maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />

        </standardEndpoint>

      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

This works when I have `http` *and* `https` bindings both configured for my website.

I connect to service via https and everything works great.

Now I want to remove `http` binding on IIS completely. And I started to get error like this:

> Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the
>   endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes
>   are [https].
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Could not find a base address that matches
>   scheme http for the endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding. Registered
>   base address schemes are [https].]
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.MakeAbsoluteUri(Uri
>   relativeOrAbsoluteUri, Binding binding, UriSchemeKeyedCollection
>   baseAddresses) +16582113
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.ConfigureEndpointAddress(ServiceEndpointElement
>   serviceEndpointElement, ServiceHostBase host, ServiceEndpoint
>   endpoint) +117
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.ConfigureEndpoint(StandardEndpointElement
>   standardEndpointElement, ServiceEndpointElement
>   serviceEndpointElement, ContextInformation context, ServiceHostBase
>   host, ServiceDescription description, ServiceEndpoint& endpoint,
>   Boolean omitSettingEndpointAddress) +937
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LookupEndpoint(ServiceEndpointElement
>   serviceEndpointElement, ContextInformation context, ServiceHostBase
>   host, ServiceDescription description, Boolean
>   omitSettingEndpointAddress) +8728167
>   System.ServiceModel.Web.WebServiceHost.AddAutomaticWebHttpBindingEndpoints(ServiceHost
>   host, IDictionary`2 implementedContracts, String
>   multipleContractsErrorMessage, String standardEndpointKind) +982
>   System.ServiceModel.Web.WebServiceHost.OnOpening() +311
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout) +612
>   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath) +255
>   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath) +1172
>
> [ServiceActivationException: The service '/DEMO/mobile' cannot be
>   activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception
>   message is: Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for
>   the endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address
>   schemes are [https]..]    System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult
>   result) +901424
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult
>   result) +178702
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +136

I found bunch of samples for WCF but REST WCF looks different on config side and I want to understand *why* it compains. From looks of my config - it should not work over SSL at all but it *does* work when https binding present..

Comment: If you want to remove the http binding on IIS just right click on the website select edit bindings option and delete the http protocol from the bindings list. That should be enough

Comment: No. If I do that - I get exactly error I posted.

Comment: Are you trying to access the url with http?

Comment: No.I want to leave HTTPS only. If I remove http binding I get this error

Comment: Can you create a new website and just map the https binding and deploy your application in that website and check if thatworks?

Comment: It's a problem with web.config, not with IIS/mappings. It is the same on 4 different servers.

Comment: why remove it and not use httpGetEnabled="false" under the serviceBehaviors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do what the error says... fix your binding

```
 <services>
      <service name="service" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="https"
contract="IContract" behaviorConfiguration="endpointBehavior">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services> 

<bindings>
 <webHttpBinding>
  <binding name="https" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
    <security mode="Transport" />
    <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                        maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                        maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />

  </binding>
 </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: This is not actually a solution to the asked question, because the original poster was using standard endpoints and this answer requires an explicit endpoint. For someone who can easily switch to an explicit endpoint, I guess it's OK. I can't, though, so I don't have an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer did not work for me because I needed to keep my standard endpoints element. I was able to remove my http-binding and only leave the https-binding in IIS by adding a `<webHttpBinding>` section to my Web.config

**Make sure to not set the `name` property on the `<binding>`, otherwise this will not work**

Relevant part of my Web.config:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding>
          <!-- Comment out the following line if HTTP is used. If HTTPS is used, leave it enabled -->
          <security mode="Transport"/>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="false" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: [The ` <standardEndpoints><webHttpEndpoint>` element doesn't have any child elements defined](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/webhttpendpoint) - so where did you get `<standardEndpoint name="" ...>` from?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
<standardEndpoints>
  <webHttpEndpoint>
    <!--Set limit to 5 megabytes-->
    <standardEndpoint helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="5242880">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                    maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                    maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />

    </standardEndpoint>
    <security mode="Transport" />
  </webHttpEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: The element 'webHttpEndpoint' has invalid child element 'security'. List of possible elements expected: 'standardEndpoint, remove, clear'.

Comment: I downvoted this answer for being _just-plain-wrong_: [`<webHttpEndpoint>` has no children](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/webhttpendpoint) and [`<standardEndpoint` does not have a `maxReceivedMessageSize` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/standardendpoints), nor does it have a `<readerQuotas>` child element.