# Disable http protocl for wcf rest asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, rest

I am working with asp.net mvc and wcf rest.
i hosted rest service inside asp.net mvc.
and config file looks like this

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false"/>
      </webHttpEndpoint>


    </standardEndpoints>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

and global.ascx

```
   protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("Rest", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(Rest)));
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
```

my asp.net web application can be accessed using http or https.
but i want to use rest api only with https how can i disable http protocol for wcf rest api.
i do not have .svc file.

Answer (score 0):

Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9548863/configure-ssl-binding-for-restful-wcf-how) help ?  You dont list the bindings settings in your quesiton, but it is here that this is usually configured.

```
<security mode="Transport"/>
```

is the key part in all of this.

Comment: because i do not have..and it is running in iis with asp.net mvc

Comment: I think you may still need a bindings section also the important point is that you set security mode="Transport"

Comment: i added binding but standardEndpoint does not support binding configration it shows error

Answer (score 0):

May be you can do it using following configuration

```
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding>
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<standardEndpoints>
  <webHttpEndpoint>
    <!-- 
        Configure the WCF REST service base address via the global.asax.cs file and the default endpoint 
        via the attributes on the <standardEndpoint> element below
    -->
    <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true">
      <security mode="Transport" >

      </security>
    </standardEndpoint>
  </webHttpEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>
```